# Bar chart labelling issue with Matplotlib and PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a bar chart embedded in a `QWidget`. When the window size of my GUI is maximum, the chart looks great (see picture 1) but when I reduce the size of the window, ticks labels almost disapear (see picture 2).
How can I preserve my labels and how can I avoid labels overlaping on each others?

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Here my code:

```
class Graph_init(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.fig.patch.set_facecolor("None")
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class Graph_populate(Graph_init):

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        n=3
        label = ['','Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre']

        x1 = [0.7,1.7,2.7,3.7,4.7,5.7,6.7,7.7,8.7,9.7,10.7,11.7]
        x2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        x3 = [1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3,11.3,12.3]

        y1 = [15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105,115,125]
        y2 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]
        y3 = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130]

        self.axes.bar(x1,y1,width=0.80/n)
        self.axes.bar(x2,y2,width=0.80/n)
        self.axes.bar(x3,y3,width=0.80/n)
        self.axes.set_xticks(np.arange(13))
        self.axes.set_xticklabels(label)
        self.axes.patch.set_facecolor('None')
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to happen when it is reduced in size? Do you want scrollbar to appear? Do you want the plot to be reduced in size?

Comment: I want the plot to be reduced in size but just enough to see labels.

Comment: I understand that you want the height to be reduced, and what do you want if the width is reduced, there will be little space to place the text, do you want the font to become smaller?

Comment: The font can become smaller up to a certain font size, the idea is to get a readable chart where space allocated to the chart is optimized. I don't know if matplotlib proposes a kind of *optimizer" of space.

Comment: And if the size is so small that you can not reduce the font then you want it to happen, you should know that since it is your requirement, for me it would be enough to establish a minimum size to the widget. what is it that you desire?

Comment: Is it possible to rotate labels with an angle of 45 degrees when labels start to overlap? Of course, the height of the bar chart will be reduced but it can be a good compromise.

Comment: I think that is a good option but the option to put a minimum size to the window, I do not think anyone wanted to see such a small graph.

Comment: I agree with you to put a minimum size on the window but how to avoid labels to be pushed outside the QWidget as shown in the second picture?

Comment: Following our discussion, I have two more questions. I set a minimum width but it can't be minimal that there is no overlapping (i.e. the graph has to be reduced a little bit). I added rotated labels but the height of the chart remains the same meaning that half of my labels are not visible. How can I constraint the chart to reduce the height? The second question is how can integrate a signal that if the width of the widget is below X then labels are rotated otherwise labels remains horizontal?

Comment: All of this is much too broad. Think step by step. Are you able to connect a signal to a slot or use the matplotlib `resize_event`? Are you able to rotate a label? Are you aware of `.tight_layout` or `.subplot_params` and know how to use them? You may find solutions to each individual problem very easily, just decouple them from the overall goal and only bring them together at the very end.

Comment: I am aware of `.tight_layout` and `.subplot_params` but it doesn't work like I wish. For example, the picture 2 above uses the `.tight_layout` but labels are pushed out from the `QWidget`. I am able to connect a `resize_event` but I am not able to get as a return the width of my `QWidget`.

Comment: So the actual problem is much narrower than the question suggests. Why don't you update the question with the actual problem and the code that produces this problem? (Note that if you want to notify me or anyone else to have a look use the @ notation inside the comment, else one will only see this by pure coincidence)